# Detecting user@hostname from within ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to create a version of `pwd` that returns the full pathway for `scp` so

```
user@hostname.ext:directory_path
```

I found that `user` can be detected using `whoami`. The directory path can of course be found using `pwd`. Can I also detect the `hostname.ext` part from the terminal? I found that `hostname` does not return the correct name but instead some abbreviation.

Comment: Are you looking to do this before you actually scp to the remote machine?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question since OP wanted to create a version of a `pwd` command, which is somehow related to programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hostname --fqdn` to display the **fully qualified domain name**, ie the hostname (what you probably called an abbreviation) with the DNS domain name.

Example:

```
amessihel@tizighennif.tg:~$ alias spwd='echo "$(whoami)@$(hostname --fqdn):$PWD"'
amessihel@tizighennif.tg:~$ spwd 
amessihel@tizighennif.tg:/home/amessihel
```

Comment: Thank you. It is strange this gives me something longer but still not the hostname that I use to log in. I will see whether using this in scp works but it looks suspect since it is quite a generic name (`hpc.cm.cluster`).

Comment: A given IP can be mapped to multiple host names. I think this is another question then, and might belong in Server Fault or Unix Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

One option with environment variables:

```sh
echo "$USER@$HOSTNAME:$PWD"
```

Second option with commands:

```sh
echo "$(logname)@$(hostname -f):$(pwd)"
```

Edit: if you want the IP address of your hostname, you can change `hostname -f` to `hostname -i`.

The second option is probably more reliable, since those environment variables may not be set. For more info about USER vs whoami vs logname and more, check out some answers to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks. I guess that would usually be a full answer. Unfortunately in this case `scp` is not working when I use the ip adress instead of the `hostname.ext`. (It gets stuck forever without an error message). So it seems I will have to supply the `hostname.ext` that I use to login my self by hand, since the values I can retrieve with hostname do not help me.

Comment: My guess is that IP address is a local one, and you're looking for thr public IP of your server? If you run `curl https://api64.ipify.org`, that should print out your public IP address.

Comment: Another couple options you have: change your hostname by changing /etc/hostname. Or you could change /etc/hosts.txt to have an entry with your hostname.ext and public IP address

Comment: Also, what exactly is it you're trying to do? I'm assuming you're trying to copy something from machine A to machine B?

Comment: Thanks I will also try the ipify suggestion. I'm trying to simplify copying files to and from the remote location. Ideally I would load the current remote directory path including the user and server into my clipboard with one command so that locally I can easily use scp to copy. (There is another obstacle to this since I don't have the priviliges to use xclip, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621167/pipe-to-the-clipboard-in-command-line-with-no-root-privilege-to-install. But at least outputting the full path would eliminate one step.)

Comment: I can, and of course for now have, just hardcoded the hostname but it would be cleaner to extract it so that the alias I use is portable across servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228312/discussion-between-kimbo-and-kvothe).

Answer (score 1):

The hostname and the FQDN associated in DNS records with IP addresses are different things and can be totally different names.

- The hostname you find in `/etc/hostname` designates the current system specific internal name. Take it as a courtesy nickname you see displayed within your shell prompt once logged-in to the system.
  The hostname is unique to the system.
- Multiple **F**ully **Q**ualified **D**omain **N**ames can point to one or more IP addresses that leads to one or more system hosts.
  An alternative to using DNS services, is to populates entries into the `/etc/hosts` with IP addresses and FQDN names.
  DNS FQDNs can resolve to different names or IP addresses depending on which DNS service you ask. This is often used to serve varying answers depending on the query location. Local DNS services (within the LAN) often gives different names and IP addresses.
  A System can be accessed by resolving multiple FQDN DNS Name.

It look like you are after the FQDN of this virtual hosts so it can be used to access it from outside or the internet.

If your local DNS service returns a generic name `hpc.cm.cluster`, it is because it is the FQDN that points to its LAN IP address within the cluster. It is not an internet exposed FQDN. For finding one of the publicly exposed FQDN and IP address, you must query a public DNS resolver outside the cluster or some other database.

I'd advise you to reroute your question to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (Networking / System Administration) instead as this place here is about programming related questions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm open to the migration but I don't think I can request it myself (at my reputation on this stackexchange, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gethostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) functionality in the `socket` module.

This will get the `hostname` of the machine where the Python interpreter is running:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: Thank you! The python tag was accidental because it remained from an unasked question. Still I'm happy for any solution so it is certainly okay to use python. Unfortunately it returns the same host name abbreviation as `hostname` does in the command line and not the full hostname. Perhaps my problem is with the way the server is set up.